# VPN and Local Network IP Conflict

Tags: networking, routing, ip

I'm running into an issue on my network.

I have a local network that connects to a router with an address of 10.0.0.1.

I also have a Router on the VPN that with the same IP of 10.0.0.1.

Unfortunately due to the conflict I am unable to connect to the VPN router (It connects for a short time then it disconnects).

Is there a way to resolve this conflict without changing the IP address of the devices?

Much appreciated!

Comment: If you are the admin of one of the networks, I would renumber it. Otherwise you should better specify your network configuration (the OS on your machine, the kind of VPN, which machines are the endpoints of the VPN tunnel, the IP addresses: mask the public ones, but give the private ones).

Comment: Can you provide a network diagram showing how these interconnect as its not obvious. It might be possible to overcome this with NAR depending on the layout. Anything in this nature would be a less then ideal solution.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot connect to a VPN that uses the same subnet, your Client simply cannot direct traffic correctly.
You'll have to re-ip your end or the VPN, depending on which causes the least risk/hassle.

To clarify, its not the router's IP specifically that is the issue here, it's the subnets your networkruns on (e.g. 10.0.0.0/24).
If these overlap/conflict, the VPN WILL fail or act erratically.